# Writing an inverse of sexual shaming toward men

Tags: creative-writing

I'm working on a matriarchal setting in which sex is viewed less stringently than our world. It is more acceptable, even expected, for women to be experienced in these matters. I am going for an inverse in sexual shaming. instead of it focusing on women for having multiple partners, is directed toward men who fail to please their lovers. I unfortunately can't think of any analogies to real life in which derogatory terms or attitudes used in this manner. How can I write this into a story?

Comment: I don't think you need to go too far. Men have always received criticism for being "too small" or "too quick" or fail to perform in bed.

Comment: See, e.g., Missy Elliot's ["One Minute Man"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cy22Woq_Ls)

Comment: I fail to see how this is different from real life. Many men like to brag about their abilities to please women and feel insulted if their partner fake it. Also being impotent really takes a toll on a man, they feel ashamed toward other males and guilty toward their partner.

Comment: Are you referring to societal pressures (some good examples of the like above), or a more systemic discrimination, abuse, and power imbalance? While the comments above hit the mark with those pressures that exist for men even in our society, I think you would need to go a bit further if your world is more of a historically misandrous one. Liquid’s answer is excellent for that case.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can really play this in a number of ways. Since you want a inverse shaming, just think of all the pressure women are exposed to in our word and turn it around.

As someone mentioned, there is already some social stigma on men who underperform in bed, but in our world this is often something unsaid. What you need to do is to take out this performance anxiety into the open.

Just think about it: in our world, "slut" and "whore" are probably among the most commonly used insults toward women, while you rarely accuse a man of being a poor partner. Men have other derogatory terms (like "faggot", since it's another way to express sexism. Ofc I'm not alright with any of this happening, I'm just stating facts).

In your world, it must be common for men to be insulted in a similar way. You could make up with some creative insults and neologisms, such as "weakie" or "quickie" or whatever. Remember thought that men don't have to be judged on their actual performance in bed - sexism can run on much less.

There will be social expectations about how a strong man will look and act like in your society, so all men will be expected to follow the rule. If all men have to be, behave, dress, talk, or even walk in some way, anyone who doesn't comply tho the norm could be subject to insults. 
In other words there will be a strong social pressure to look like the ideal man. 
As a side effect, sexual anxiety will increase, and most men will probably take up pills - as viagra - even in their youth.

Comment: There already are social expectations for how boys will behave.  Cry, and you're open season for every bully.\

Comment: You're right; Shard, however, asked for ways to emphasize social expectations toward men and make them more prominent.